# Mongodb query using javascript file - format datetime

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am using mongodb3.0.5 and my collection looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "SchoolId" : 1,
    "ActivationTimestamp" : ISODate("2015-09-22T13:01:58.000Z"),
    "PersonDetails" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "John",
            "AddressZone" : 6,
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Mary",
            "AddressZone" : 5,
        },
    ],
    "CreationTimestamp" : ISODate("2015-11-10T10:55:00.009Z")
}
```

I have a js file like this:

```
var printData = function(doc){
        print(doc.CreationTimestamp+","+doc.SchoolId+","+doc.PersonDetails.Name+","+doc.PersonDetails.AddressZone)
    };

var cur = 
    db.test.aggregate([
        {$match: {_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}},
        {$unwind: '$PersonDetails'}]);

cur.forEach(printData);
```

If I run this command:

```
.\mongo localhost/test test.js > output.txt
```

I get the following ouput(didn't include all lines just a sample):

**Tue Sep 22 2015 14:01:58 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time),1,John,6**

But I would like the date to have a format of something like:

22/09/2015 14:01:58

Is there a function or something to output the datetime as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the date and put it in a javascript date object:

```
var d = new Date(doc.CreationTimestamp);
```

Now you can massage it however you want:

```
var date = d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds();
```

Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp for all the functions you can call on a date object.